# Detailed Minting policy documentation?

Tags: nft, policy

I found several Articles which deal with Minting Policy's for native tokens as:

- https://cardano-ledger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/explanations/policies.html#minting-policy
- https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/simple-scripts.md
- https://docs.cardano.org/en/latest/native-tokens/getting-started-with-native-tokens.html#token-minting-policies

But none of them has a detailed desciption of syntax and functions provided in smartcontracts as of today (mary era).
Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there, the token policy scripts are actually the multisig/nativescripts. As you know token policy's are not turing complete contracts, for that you should be looking at Plutus. Here's the documentation regarding the NativeScripts as scripts to use as token policy with all syntax and features.

https://docs.cardano.org/projects/cardano-node/en/latest/reference/simple-scripts.html

Comment: thnx Ashish that was the pointer I was looking for.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. Here's the archived page: https://web.archive.org/web/20210601112403/https://docs.cardano.org/projects/cardano-node/en/latest/reference/simple-scripts.html

Comment: Whoever decided to change the above URL and dumb-down the whole website and make it flashy is a horrible person